# How to upgrade TLS version from 1.0 to 1.2 in Oracle WebTier?

Tags: oracle, ssl, tls1.2

How to upgrade TLS version from 1.0 to 1.2 in Oracle Web Tier? Oracle Web Tier has WebCache 11.1.1.7.0 and Oracle HTTP Server (I couldn't find out which version we have).

Comment: What is the value specified in your httpd.conf file for the SSLProtocol directive? If it's "ALL", you're out of luck in finding a simple solution. Oracle HTTP Server 11.1.1.x does not support TLS 1.2 and you may have to try something like this: https://technology.amis.nl/2014/12/07/securing-ohs-environments-latest-ssl-tls-protocols-sha-2-certificates/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I dont see any SSLProtocol directive defined in httpd.conf file of Oracle HTTP Server.